# Is a GCP Firewall Rule applied on an instance which shares the same target tag/network tag but is on a different network?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-load-balancer

I am following instructions given in a [Lab Challenge - Creating an Internal Load Balancer](https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/focuses/1250?parent=catalog)
The test comes with a `my-internal-app` network pre-configured (along with the usual `default` network).

It then asks the student to create everything(instances, firewall rules, load balancer, etc.) in the `my-internal-app` network and its subnets but strangely the instruction to create the fire-wall rule - `app-allow-health-check`, for the health checker, does not mention the `my-internal-app` and thus need to be created in the `default` network instead of the `my-internal-app` network???

A caveat, however, is that the target tag mentioned while creating this rule - `app-allow-health-check`, is specified as `lb-backend` which is also used as the network tag for the managed instance group template(and thus indirectly for the VM instances being created as part of it).

So, my question is whether the target tag overrides the network which is specified for the firewall rule and is thus applied to instances using the same tag as their network tag even though they are created in a different network.